# Is this proof than Piccolo is stronger than Trunks and Goten in DBZ?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-z

In Dragon Ball Z, when Goku was fighting "Buutenks" (not an official name), the kids lose the fusion inside Buu and Buu gets a caped Piccolo-like appearance. According to Japanese subtitles, Goku says to Buu: "The half-pints have returned to normal from their fusion. Piccolo is coming out strongest".

Is this proof that Piccolo was stronger than Trunks and Goten or is there something else in the series that shows otherwise?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYdXZ9ut8qk

Comment: I would suggest rephrasing the question to something along the lines, "Who is stronger in Buu Saga, Piccolo or Goten/Trunks?". In the present form the "Authenticity" of said proof would be opinion based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is established at the end of Cell Saga Piccolo was stronger than ssj1(Android 17/18), but weaker than ssj1+ or Cell. Piccolo with his intense training techniques would have only grown stronger.

Since Goten and Trunks are shown only capable of going till ssj1 while unfused we can conclude that Piccolo is stronger then them. *The Buutenks avatar switching to Piccollo may or may not be the conclusive evidence you wish it to be*, but majority of DB Community believes Piccolo was stronger than unfused Goten/Trunks.

Further on this point, seperately the kids struggled against Android 18 2 vs 1. We didn't get to see the full fight but it can be assumed Piccolo is still stronger than Android 18 and hence the base ssj1 Kids.

Answer (score 0):

More on the power level of Piccolo has been revealed in Dragon Ball Super

> He can defeat Gohan in Super Saiyan 2 in a training match